# nginx location rewrite: match /{?x}, {y}, {?z}. Remove y

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx, regular-expression

I am trying to run CiviCRM with Drupal 7 in a docker container of my own design.

Unfortunately, I am running into a problem where for some unknown reason CiviCRM is outputting resource requests malformatted. Sometimes like this ('...' conotates the rest of the path to the resource):

```
/... (good)
/civicrm/... (good)
```

Sometimes like this:

```
/civicrm/sitename/... (bad)
```

Sometimes like this:

```
/sitename/... (bad)
```

Sometimes like this:

```
/civicrm/sitename/civicrm (bad)
```

Sometimes like this:

```
/civicrm/sitename/civicrm/sitename/... (very bad)
```

And so on, possibly infinitum:

```
/civicrm/sitename/civicrm/sitename/civicrm/... (very bad)
```

Now regex's are not my forte. After much humming and harring, I have managed to produce the following:

```
    location /civicrm/sitename {
            rewrite ^/civicrm/sitename/(.*)$ /$1;
    }

    location /sitename/ {
            rewrite ^/sitename/(.*)$ /$1;
    }
```

Now many of the resources load better but this does not catch all of the problems. The  best I can define it is this:

```
#If the URL contains a / followed by any characters or none followed by a / followed by sitename followed by any characters or none, remove sitename:
rewrite /(?./)sitename/(?.)$ $;
# Then continue processing the next directive.
#If the rewritten URL contains /civicrm/ more than once, remove all instances of /civicrm/ then add it once:
rewrite /(?./)civicrm/civicrm/(?.)$ /civicrm/$;
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

> If the URL contains a / followed by any characters or none followed by
>   a / followed by sitename followed by any characters or none, remove
>   sitename:

```
rewrite ^(.+)/sitename(/.*)$ $1$2;
```

Explanation: you need to capture everything before (`$1`) and after (`$2`) the match, in order to construct the result.

> If the rewritten URL contains /civicrm/ more than once, remove all
>   instances of /civicrm/ then add it once:

```
rewrite "^(.*?)(?:/civicrm){2,}(/.*?)$" $1/civicrm$2;
```

Explanation: As above, except that two or more non-capturing `/civicrm` strings are matched and the first and last capture are lazy. Expressions containing a `{` should be quoted.

Useful resource for regular expressions is [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html).